# Google Script UI dialog window doesn't open

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script

This is just a simple script, since I'm new at coding in Google Script.  I used their code to test a dialog, but the dialog window doesn't even open.  Obviously I'm missing a piece of code, but am at a loss as to what.  Here's my code.  Thanks in advance!

```
function demoUI() {
  var myapp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('An improved GUI');

  var mygrid = myapp.createGrid(3, 2);
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 0, myapp.createLabel('Name:'));
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 1, myapp.createTextBox());
  mygrid.setWidget(1, 0, myapp.createLabel('Age:'));
  mygrid.setWidget(1, 1, myapp.createTextBox());
  mygrid.setWidget(2, 0, myapp.createLabel('City'));
  mygrid.setWidget(2, 1, myapp.createTextBox());

  var mybutton = myapp.createButton('Press me');
  var mypanel = myapp.createVerticalPanel();
  mypanel.add(mygrid);
  mypanel.add(mybutton);
  myapp.add(mypanel);
  return myapp;
}
```

Comment: This function just builds a UI object... How are you trying to display that UI? You can either [publish a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app) or as a [dialog or sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) from a script bound to a doc or sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `return myapp;` with

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
spreadsheet.show(myapp);
```

This example is for Google Sheets. You would need to change the code based on what app you are using.

However, the [UiApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app), which you are using, is deprecated. Use the [HTML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) to create Google Apps Script User Interfaces instead.